# How to log whatever I enter in terminal to file

Tags: terminal, io-redirection

I am a novice just learning Fedora 13. I just wanted to know if its possible to redirect whatever I type in the terminal to a file, so that I would be able to see from the file, that a particular command gives this output.

So whatever I am doing should go to a file.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [`script` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unix%29).  After you execute it everything that happens in your terminal will be recorded to a file which you can open up later to review what happened.

Another useful command is [`ttyrec`](http://0xcc.net/ttyrec/index.html.en) which records not only the input/output of your terminal session but also timing information.  This lets you to play back your terminal session later like a movie using `ttyplay`.

Comment: +1 for ttyrec - yet another command I had never heard of before.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to write to a new file called test.txt. Just type this on the command line:

```
cat > test.txt
```

Press enter and start writing. To finish your session press `CTRL + d`. A text file, test.txt will be created in the same directory, with the content you typed.

Answer (score 0):

To store output in a file you can use `>`  after the command.

Example :

```
ls -a > file.txt
```

The above command will list all the files in the working directory into file.txt

```
df -h > file.txt
```

The above command will save your file system usage in file.txt

Hope this explanation answers your question